# Rails pry-byebug not accessed

Tags: puts, binding.pry

I am trying to debug my code using the pry-byebug tool, but when I launch "rails console" in my terminal and then call on the class method in which the debugger should come into action, nothing happens. I have installed the gem and did a bundle install as per the documentation on:
https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug

So basically I have 2 models, Grid and Cell. When a Grid instance is created I want to create the corresponding Cell instances. So far it doesn't work, but my main problem is that I am not able to debug and know where things go wrong.

I have therefore added the binding.pry command in the create method of the Grid class. Hoping to go through the rest of the code line by line and understand where I did something wrong.

However when in "rails console" I do something like Grid.new(session_id: 1, rows: 3, columns: 3), all I see is that the instance has been created and saved to the DB.

So I manage accessing the method "create" but not showing either the puts nor getting the pry-byebug options.

Even my logs don't show any error message.

I have read other posts on that subject but none have worked for me so far, such as this one:
[Breakpoints with pry-byebug don't trigger in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965956/breakpoints-with-pry-byebug-dont-trigger-in-the-console)

Here is my GridController

```
require "pry-byebug"

class GridsController < ApplicationController

  # after_create :generate_cells_for_grid

  after_action :generate_cells_for_grid, only: [:create]


  def new
    @grid = Grid.new
  end

  def create
    puts "In the CREATE method" # This puts never shows up in the console
    binding.pry
    @grid = Grid.new()
    @grid.save
  end

  def generate_cells_for_grid
    rows = @grid.rows
    columns = @grid.columns
    id = @grid.id

    # Creating cells for every position to fill the grid
    for row in 1..rows do
      puts row
      for column in 1..columns do
        puts row
        puts column
        Cell.create({
          grid_id: 1,
          player_id: 1,
          colour_id: 1,
          x_coordonate: row,
          y_coordonate: column,
          alive: false
        })
      end
    end
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
    @grid = Grid.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @grid = Grid.find(params[:id])
    @grid.update(params[:grid])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def delete
  end
end
```

This is what I get in the "rails console":

```
[30] pry(main)> Grid.create(session_id: 1, rows: 3, columns: 3)
   (1.7ms)  BEGIN
  Session Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" WHERE "sessions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Grid Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "grids" ("session_id", "rows", "columns", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["session_id", 1], ["rows", 3], ["columns", 3], ["created_at", "2019-11-07 11:07:08.951668"], ["updated_at", "2019-11-07 11:07:08.951668"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Grid:0x00007fce6b2cf790
 id: 31,
 session_id: 1,
 rows: 3,
 columns: 3,
 created_at: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 11:07:08 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 11:07:08 UTC +00:00>
```

What am I doing wrong to not activate the pry-byebug? Is there a more efficient way to debug on Rails?

Thanks!